# Why can any number of slashes work in a path or URL?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, path

I noticed today I was incorrectly concatenating directory names in a script and wound up with multiple slashes between two folders (EX: `c:\users\sidney\\desktop`. I noticed that the code works, even though I wouldn't expect it to. I tried `cd`ing to a path in cmd as well and found that using multiple slashes properly resolves a path in CMD, and I was able to navigate to this page with `https://superuser.com/questions///ask` (notice three slashes before ask)

[image: CMD prompt showing multiple slashes can be used in a file path and it still works]

It's nice that it works, but what is actually going on behind the scenes when multiple slashes are present in a path? I assume under the covers `desktop\\\\\\New folder` would resolve to `["desktop","","","","","","New Folder"] and try and navigate to a folder with a blank name, but that doesn's appear to be the case.

Comment: Looks like this was answered over on StackExchange proper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027024/documented-behavior-for-multiple-backslashes-in-windows-paths

Answer (score 3):

The answer may be found in Microsoft's article
[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file):

> Use a backslash ('\') to separate the components of a path. The backslash divides the file name from the path to it, and one directory name from another directory name in a path. You cannot use a backslash in the name for the actual file or directory because it is a reserved character that separates the names into components.

The function of the backslash is to be a separator, so multiple consecutive
backslashes still only separate and cannot create new components.
Meaning that `\\` cannot create a new empty component - no path component
can be empty.

Most operating systems allow the inclusion of multiple slashes between file name or directory components of a file path. This is true of both Windows and most *nix operating systems. The only exception is slashes used in conjunction with a UNC,
where only two backward slashes are allowed with the UNC (`\\?\UNC\`).

For the same question about Linux, see
[this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/17660).

Answer (score 1):

> What is actually going on behind the scenes when multiple slashes are present in a path?

In most cases, they are simply being ignored during parsing. However, this depends entirely on the program/system doing the path parsing.

As given by @r-greenstreet, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027024/documented-behavior-for-multiple-backslashes-in-windows-paths) has a [comments sections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027325) that points out at least one exception to this rule in Windows as `dir c:\\`. In that case, `dir c:` and `dir c:\` work properly, whereas `dir c:\\` does not (i.e. the second `\` directory separator causes a parsing issue).

Regarding URLs (which are typically parsed by a web server and effectively have little relation to the underlying OS), there are similar exceptions as pointed out in [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161177/url-with-multiple-forward-slashes-does-it-break-anything). Particularly, multiple `/` path separators can interfere with internal URL rewriting and relative paths.

> I assume under the covers `desktop\\\\\\New folder` would resolve to `["desktop","","","","","","New Folder"]` and try and navigate to a folder with a blank name, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

I am fairly confident that (only) blank spaces cannot be valid directory names in Windows, so I would imagine most parses (for Windows at least) would take this into account. Note that the extra separators are not necessarily treated as "blank" names either — `"C:\path\to\some\\folder"` will likely work while `"C:\path\to\some\ \folder"` will likely not.